# Techniques to avoid race conditions in an inverted index algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, search, computer-science, inverted-index

I'm building an inverted index algorithm. I'll be storing the index in the form of a hashtable  in a file or database. Updating the index involves 
1. Loading it into memory, from the file or database
2. Converting it into an object 
3. Making changes to the object
4. Converting the object into a string
5. Saving it in the file or database

Now, there are multiple sources that feed data into the index. If 2 or more sources try to feed in data simultaneously, there's a pretty good chance of running into race conditions.

What are the best known techniques to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you wouldn't load the whole index into memory and then write the whole index back to disk later.

One option is to have the index primarily on disk, and just modify the file on the disk directly. To avoid race conditions, you use some form of a lock. You can globally lock the file for writing if updates are rare. If you want to have more fine grained locking then you need to make more decisions about the structure of the index on disk.

Another option is to have the index in memory, and just maintain a "copy" on disk for recovery purposes. In that case, everyone updating the index would manipulate eventually the same, shared in-memory index, and access to that would be protected by global or fine-grained operating system level locks.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Will it be a good idea to store the index in a database in a fully normalized form? Or will this consume too much space and time compared to raw files?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451919/what-is-the-best-way-to-build-inverted-index)